# ng angular cli version Notification warning

Tags: angular, build

Whenever I run ng command I am getting this warning

```
Your global Angular CLI version (1.6.8) is greater than your local version (1.6.0). The local Angular CLI version is used.
To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
```

How can I fix this?

When I Build at that time I am using the below command to ignore the warnings.

```
ng build --prod --aot=false
```

Do anyone came acorss this.?

Comment: Update your local angular cli by `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@1.6.8 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem by changing my angular CLI version using below command

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@1.6.8
```

Check your package-lock.json for your angular version and change the version in above command.

Answer (score 0):

Angular-cli gives you this warning because you have globally installed angular-cli v1.6.8, you can check it by `ng --version`. However, your project has angular-cli v1.6.0 in its `devDependencies`. When you run `ng build`, you are using globally installed angular-cli, since it is different than locally installed one, it may cause some unpredicted behaviors. 
You should add a script to your `package.json` (probably you already have)

`package.json`

```
....
"scripts": {
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot",
}
```

When you run this script through `npm` like this `npm run build`, it'll use locally installed angular-cli which will not give that warning.

Also, you should not use `ng` directly, because you could have different angular projects in your machine and all of them may depend on different angular-cli versions. If you build them all by `ng`, there could be some build errors.

Think of this other scenario, let's say you work in a big company with hundreds of developers. Many teams develop angular projects or maybe other projects as well, and you have one CI machine at your company. Every project is built on this single machine. Since, you guys are web developers, that machine needs to have `npm` installed. That's fine. However, some people may use angular-cli, some people may use webpack or some other teams develop React and they need other tools. You can't possible install them globally by `npm install -g <insert-tool-here>` on this shared CI machine. This will cause version mismatch between teams and many mistakes. Also, it would be hard to maintain them all. What, in this scenario, every team needs to do is to put their tools `devDependencies` and run them through `npm scripts`.

Hope this clarifies it for you.